# Include command line in Sketchware?

Tags: android, sketchware

I'm thinking of creating a nice gui for ffmpeg command line using Sketchware. Is it possible to add a ffmpeg build into a Sketchware project?

Comment: Help here, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68856451/hw-to-fix-this-sketchware-problem-when-run-please

Answer (score 0):

I'd say kinda, you will need an arm-compiled ffmpeg (with it's library statically-linked i believe) for that, and if i'm not wrong, you can execute ffmpeg directly using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path/to/ffmpeg -arguments");`

So it goes on like this:

- First, you'll need to include the arm-compiled ffmpeg into your app and extract it at launch at `getFilesDir()` directory,
- Second, the ffmpeg needs to be `chmod u+x ffmpeg`-ed to allow the user to execute the binary.
- Third, just use the above code, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path/to/ffmpeg -arguments")`

Though, I've heard some news that Android 11 is going to restrict binary execution like this.

Another note, I haven't really tried this myself, but if i have time, I'll probably update this answer.

I just found out a precompiled ffmpeg binary that is used on termux [here](https://10.via0.com/ipns/k51qzi5uqu5dg9vawh923wejqffxiu9bhqlze5f508msk0h7ylpac27fdgaskx/pool/main/f/ffmpeg). All you need to do is to manually change the library locaiton to the extracted library location.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question well
, But if you want cmd this class does it

```
public class CommandLine{
    private BufferedReader r;
    private Process p;
    private ProcessBuilder builder;
    private String LinesString = null;
    public String run(String command)throws Exception{
        
        builder = new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" "));
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        p = builder.start();
        r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        Object[] lines = r.lines().toArray();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            if(LinesString == null){
                LinesString = lines[i].toString();
                
            }else{
                LinesString = LinesString + " "+lines[i].toString();
                
            }
            
        }
        return LinesString;
        
    }
}
```

Until you run this class :

```
try{

    String out = new CommandLine().run("echo hi");
} catch (Exception e) {
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well,
because it's not even for android, it's quite impossible.
If FFmpeg was for Android, in theory it would be possible.
It is impossible to make a command line for FFmpeg in Android on Sketchware (that is, if you do not need to program any emulators;))
Probably the only option would be a Linux terminal emulator, but in Basic Sketchware I doubt it would work. Otherwise, in sketchware you can do practically anything (especially Sketchware PRO) using the ASD block (Add source directly) which allows you to upload your own code.

**Summary; it is not possible. (Or very difficult)**

Comment: I have a few apps on Android that include an Android FFMPEG build. So it is possible, just didn't know if it was possible to use one with Sketchware.

Comment: Well yes, on Android it is possible, cause is possible to emulate linux term. But only with an emulator, its IMPOSIBLE to run FFmpeg on android without emulation. And i don´t think you want to build an emulator on Sketchware ;) So?

Comment: afaik Building an emulator is unnecessary, you can just cross-compile FFmpeg into aarch64 to make it run on an android device's cpu. Yes, FFmpeg is usually compiled with x86_64, but it can also be compiled into aarch64 with some minor patches.

Comment: Yeah, I did also find this out. Still, it's impossible to do in Sketchware, the only way is maybe Sketchware mod (That allows assets) but it's still hard, and thanks to Sketchware limitations, I don't think it can be easily made.

Comment: @LukasStudioTV There is a sneaky way of slipping assets on original sketchware, You can put the asset in a zip file, rename the extension to be a `.ttf` file, and add it as a font in sketchware. When the app is launched, stream the `.ttf` file into a specified directory, rename the extension into `.zip` and extract it :^)

Comment: But sadly, android 12 restricts binary execution on the home directory because of the [W^X Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX) :(. You have to include the FFmpeg binary into the native library resource of the app, and use the `android:extractNativeLibs="true"` on android manifest to make the system extract the files into `context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir` and make it executable. Unfortunately, This method isn't going to work on original sketchware (can't include native files), so you should better off using modded sketchware.